# Programatically going back to home page with React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've read the articles on here on how to do this and have chosen the `withRouter(({ history }) => history.push("/"));` method, but my code below isn't working.. What am I doing wrong?

```
import React from "react";
import SearchBox from "./SearchBox";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

class SearchParams extends React.Component {
  handleSearchSubmit() {
    withRouter(({ history }) => history.push("/"));
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search-route">
        <SearchBox search={this.handleSearchSubmit} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SearchParams;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) is a higher order component which takes a component as first argument and will make it so that component gets the `history` added to its regular props.

You can instead use it on the component when you export it, and access the history from `this.props.history`.

```
class SearchParams extends React.Component {
  handleSearchSubmit = () => {
    this.props.history.push("/");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search-route">
        <SearchBox search={this.handleSearchSubmit} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(SearchParams);
```